# How to set token in header after it is sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, session, jwt

I did the login in Node JS. Tested it in Postman. Works perfectly. 
Now I need to integrate it to the client with interface. How can I get token and set it header in client-side after jwt token sent in POST API?
Or is it possible to set header in server-side? This is what I tried. I just have no idea how to do it.

```
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
  var username = request.body.username;
  var password = request.body.pass;

  if (username && password) {
        db.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?', [username], function(error, results, fields) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password, function(err, res) {
          if(res) {
            jwt.sign({id: results[0].id}, 'sdfghwertyhbvcsdfghjk', (err, token) => {
              response.json({token});
              response.setHeader('Set-Cookie', ['item1=value1']);
            });
              // response.render(__dirname + "/views/bearer.html", {sessionToken: results3[0].token});
              response.end();
          } else {
            response.send('Неправильно введены данные')
            response.end();
          }
        })
            } else {
                response.send('Неправильно введены данные');
        response.end();
            }
        });
    } else {
        response.send('Введите имя пользователя и пароль');
    response.end();
    }
});

function checkRights(request, result, next, rights) {
  try {
    var id = jwt.verify(request.headers.authorization, 'sdfghwertyhbvcsdfghjk').id;
    db.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?', [id] , function(error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      if(results.length == 0) return false;
      if(rights.indexOf(results[0].username) !== -1) {
        request.user = results[0];
        next()
      } else
        result.json({
          error: "You are not allowed!!!"
        });
    });
  } catch(e) {
    result.json({
      error: "Not authorized!!!"
    });
  }
}
function Authorized (request, res, next) {
  checkRights(request, res, next, ['admin']);
}

app.get('/dashboard', [Authorized], function (req, res) {
  res.send("OK");
  res.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/introduction/)

> Whenever the user wants to access a protected route or resource, the user agent should send the JWT, typically in the Authorization header using the Bearer schema. The content of the header should look like the following:
>
> > Authorization: Bearer <token>

if you set a header on the server-side, the client should still set it itself.

[Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ju5FGcyifEA) video on how to use JWT on the client-side JavaScript